# How tov separate the given sample into 2 subsamples; positive and negative?

Tags: r, split, sample, false-positive

I am running a regression analysis on one dataset, the output consists of positive and negative residuals.
I was asked to calculate the mean values of negative residuals and positive residuals.

`c(Left.Mean = mean(Estimated.Residuals[Estimated.Residuals < 0]),  Right.Mean = mean(Estimated.Residuals[Estimated.Residuals > 0]))`

It worked well and I got output as below:

**Left.Mean Right.Mean**

**-0.7241664  0.7013580**

Now, I am asked to separate the given sample into 2 subsamples: one, for which the residuals are below zero, and another, for which they are above zero. In addition, I need to create the variable "Unscrambled.Selection.Sequence" estimating switching between the two subsamples (1 corresponds to the positive residual case and 0 corresponds to the negative residual case). Is there any ideas?

Comment: The subsample part you can do with ```library(dplyr) pos_df <- Estimated.Residuals %>% filter(Estimated.Residuals > 0)``` . The opposite for the negative. Just didnt get the new variable part

Comment: @LuizZ Thank you for your answer, I am also not quite sure about that variable, I think "switching between the two subsamples" is the key, once I filtered positive and negative residuals, this new variable called "unscrambled.selection.sequence" should include both positive and negative residuals.  For example,  `head(Unscrambled.Selection.Sequence,10)` must show me the order of the first ten residuals and their type, whether positive or negative.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).